# Is there a way to use SELECT FOUND_ROWS() in php and mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to implement a pagination system into my website and can't get past this one stubborn error. I'm not exactly sure if you can use FOUND_ROWS() in mysqli as opposed to PDO but that's what I came here for.

I have the latest version of PHP and everything worked up to this point in the pagination.

```php
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT count(*) FROM owned_assets WHERE uid=? AND type=? LIMIT '.$start.', '.$rLim);
    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $uid, $assetType);
    $stmt->execute();
    $total = $conn->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total')->mysqli_fetch_array()['total'];
```

What's supposed to happen (so far) is mysql will count the rows found within the matching query and I can work further on from there.

This is my current error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function mysqli_fetch_array() on bool

Comment: hmm, adding another query to use `FOUND_ROWS()` for the sake of getting the count is not needed, just fetch and use the initial query return value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the counting query, just fetch that value. No need for another second query `FOUND_ROWS()`.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT count(*) FROM owned_assets WHERE uid=? AND type=?');
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $uid, $assetType);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$total = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $total['count(*)'];
```

Sidenote: You can use an alias to `count(*) AS total` in the query, and access the index as `$total['total']` in the return value.

Comment: Well it worked when I made another query doing that (as when I did it with the first one it wouldn't return other values)

Comment: @RandomRando and actually doing `FOUND_ROWS()` right after the count will yield the incorrect result, I have not tested but I think doing `FOUND_ROWS()` will give you `1` every time since `count()` gives you one row. it won't work the way you're expecting it to be. remove the count and replace it to `SELECT *` then `FOUND_ROWS()` is the correct sequence. but that would need two trips, just use `COUNT(*)` and then fetch that column and thats it.

Comment: This query is essentially useless as it counts the predefined number of rows. Just saying.

Comment: @YourCommonSense good point, it should have not been there in the first place having the limit

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is but you have to follow the **proper routine**.

Your current query makes no sense as it counts the number you already know, stored in $rLim (all right not always but that's not the point).

To use FOUND_ROWS() for pagination you must add [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) to your query that fetches the data for a single page.

Then you will be able to get the total number of rows without limit by means of running another query with FOUND_ROWS().

That said, using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS is not recommended as it is **as slow as fetching all rows** without LIMIT. And this is the reason why this function was recently **deprecated**.

So you have to make two queries, one fetching the actual data with LIMIT clause and one with count(*) and without LIMIT.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need another query to get the total number of rows, as you already have it with `COUNT()`. You can just bind the result of the first query to the `$total` with **[`bind_result()`:](https://www.phptutorial.info/?mysqli-stmt.bind-result)**

```
$stmt->bind_result($total);
```